How to insert category?
How to insert A, B, C in the tree diagram below?

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=42pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree
  [.сүлд
    [.сүлд
      [.сүлд ]
      [.тоо ]
    ]
    [.\colorbox{cyan!30!}{\textcolor{red}{тоо}}
      [.сүлд ]
      [.тоо ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=42pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree
  [.тоо
    [.сүлд
      [.сүлд ]
      [.\colorbox{cyan!30!}{\textcolor{red}{тоо}} ]
    ]
    [.тоо
      [.сүлд ]
      [.тоо ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add the code for the tree?

how to insert it depends on the code you have which produces the rest. there must be a dozen or more tree packages, in addition to methods which don't use specialised tree packages. please also explain the problem. are you trying to add headers at the top or what? is the arrow part of what you want the add? is TODO part of the existing output?

The logic could be to anchor the three nodes that contain A, B and C relative to the relevant nodes of the (upper) tree and shift them up. Of course, you also need to make sure that you align them vertically. But as it was said: In order to come up with a nice solution that actually can help you, you need to show us the code for the tree at least.
